# WSO2 API Manager fails when using external ldap

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am setting up wso2 API manager to use an external LDAP so it connects to my company's user base for logins but I am getting the following error which I can't find the reason:

```
2016-09-09 10:44:32,436 [-] [Start Level Event Dispatcher] ERROR Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.buildRealmConfiguration(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:367)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.buildRealmConfiguration(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:281)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.buildBootStrapRealmConfig(DefaultRealmService.java:136)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:84)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Here is my user-mgt.xml:

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>procergs-felipe-schnack</UserName>
                <!-- Password>admin</Password -->
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://ldap1.procergs.reders:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=wso2,ou=U4S,ou=PROCERGS,o=estado,c=br</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">xxxx</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=procergs,o=Estado,c=BR</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">uid=?</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixAccount)</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute">displayname</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
            <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

What I am missing? I tried to lookup the source code in wso2 SVN repo but I am still lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Why have you commented out the admin password?

Comment: I am not creating a new admin, I would like to set my user as AM manager only. Should I set a password there? Which one?

Comment: What is the APIM Version u r using?

Comment: Check whats causing the null from here. If u tell me the exact APIM version I can point to the correct tag. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/config/UserStoreConfigXMLProcessor.java

Comment: I am using version 2.0.0... I tried to look up the sources but could not find the problem. It seemed to me that code was suggesting lack of CARBON_HOME env variable, but I have it set on the startup script as the following: export CARBON_HOME=/opt/wso2am

Comment: Did u try uncommenting the Admin user password?

Comment: I did set a password for the admin and now its up. Thanks :)

Comment: Does that mean I have to store my admin password in plaintext in this file and that I can't have more than one admin?

Comment: Please refer the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to point to a existing user in your LDAP to be the super user of the system. The super user is a special user in the system which has all the permissions to manage the system. Hence this configuration is required. You can use Ciper tool to encrypt your password and store it. You can refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool).

Comment: This is so wierd, it seems that if I left the password blank it starts anyway. The problem is that I removed the tag initially.

Comment: Interesting, in that case the server should only be needing a username. And although its looking for the password element it might not be using it. But since you have commented out it, its causing the null pointer.